# AES decryption returning empty string

Tags: encryption, aes, cryptojs

Hello i'm trying to encrypt and decrypt files (in Uint8Array format) using CryptoJS Library (3.1.2)
This is my code:

```
var WPAES = {
    keySize: 256,
    ivSize: 128,
    saltSize: 128,
    iterations:1000,
    encrypt: function(data,passphrase)
    {
        try
        {
            var iv = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(this.ivSize/8);
            console.log(iv.toString());
            var salt = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(this.saltSize/8);
            console.log(salt.toString());

            var key = CryptoJS.PBKDF2(passphrase, salt, {
              keySize: this.keySize/32,
              iterations: this.iterations
            });
            var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(CryptoJS.enc.u8array.parse(data), key, {
                iv: iv,
                padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7,
                mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC

            });

            var encryptedIv = CryptoJS.enc.u8array.stringify(iv);
            var encryptedSalt = CryptoJS.enc.u8array.stringify(salt);
            var encryptedArray = CryptoJS.enc.u8array.stringify(encrypted.ciphertext);

            var message = new Uint8Array(encryptedIv.length + encryptedSalt.length + encryptedArray.length);
            message.set(encryptedIv);
            message.set(encryptedSalt, encryptedIv.length);
            message.set(encryptedArray, encryptedIv.length+encryptedSalt.length);
            return message;
        }
        catch(e)
        {
            console.log(e);
            return false;
        }

    },
    decrypt: function(data,passphrase)
    {
        try
        {
            var iv = CryptoJS.enc.u8array.parse(data.slice(0, this.ivSize/8));
            console.log(iv.toString());
            var salt = CryptoJS.enc.u8array.parse(data.slice(this.ivSize/8, this.ivSize/8+this.saltSize/8))
            console.log(salt.toString());
            var encrypted = CryptoJS.enc.u8array.parse(data.slice(this.ivSize/8+this.saltSize/8));
            var key = CryptoJS.PBKDF2(passphrase, salt, {
              keySize: this.keySize/32,
              iterations: this.iterations
            });
            var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, key, {
                iv: iv,
                padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7,
                mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC

            });
            var res = CryptoJS.enc.u8array.stringify(decrypted.ciphertext);

            return res;
        }
        catch(e)
        {
            console.log(e);
            return false;
        }

    }
}
```

I'm also use:

```
CryptoJS.enc.u8array = {
        stringify: function (wordArray) {
            var words = wordArray.words;
            var sigBytes = wordArray.sigBytes;
            var u8 = new Uint8Array(sigBytes);
            for (var i = 0; i < sigBytes; i++) {
                var byte = (words[i >>> 2] >>> (24 - (i % 4) * 8)) & 0xff;
                u8[i]=byte;
            }
            return u8;
        },
        parse: function (u8arr) {
            var len = u8arr.length;
            var words = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                words[i >>> 2] |= (u8arr[i] & 0xff) << (24 - (i % 4) * 8);
            }
            return CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create(words, len);
        }
    };
```

But when i decrypt the file the results is empty. Ialso check the iv, salt and the encrypted message. All seems work except for the decryption that always returns an empty value.

How can i fix this problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I solved using:

```
 var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt({ciphertext:encrypted}, key, {
       iv: iv,
       padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7,
       mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC

 });
```

in decrypt function.

Answer (score 2):

Given it a long try and finally got it.

1). CryptoJS uses hex values while java uses bytes for the same String.

2.) The two other factors which need to be same (apart from the key) are initVector and padding.

Considering both above we first have to validate that both Java are CryptoJS and encrypting to the same value given the above parameters are same.

Here is the code for Java

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Base64;

public class JavaEncryptor {

    private static final String key = "aesEncryptionKey";
    private static final String initVector = "encryptionIntVec";

    public static String toHex(String arg) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        return String.format("%020x", new BigInteger(1, arg.getBytes("UTF-8")));
    }


    /**
     * Use these hex value in CryptoJS
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public static void printHexForJS() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("HexKeyForJS :  "+ toHex(key));
        System.out.println("HexInitVectorForJS :  "+ toHex(initVector));
    }

    public static String encrypt(String value) {
        try {
            IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(initVector.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");


            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, iv);

            byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(value.getBytes()); 
            return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encrypted);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        printHexForJS();
        System.out.println(encrypt("MyPlainTextToBeEncrypted"));
    }

}
```

Output of the above program is

> HexKeyForJS :  616573456e6372797074696f6e4b6579 
>   HexInitVectorForJS : 656e6372797074696f6e496e74566563
>   MURKOx14eSOo2vs8ZQyCpXpsoKg8Uzlvyj3byQreVBk=

And then for JS encryption use the HexKeyForJS  and HexInitVectorForJS as in below code

```
var text = "ManishMudgal";
var key = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(HexKeyForJS);
var iv  = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(HexInitVectorForJS);

var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(text, key, {iv: iv, padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7});
console.log(encrypted.toString());
```

> Output of the above JS code should be  kBgYcrSxz+kbXRnyKIFmSw==

Which is the same encrypted key generated through Java code 
MURKOx14eSOo2vs8ZQyCpXpsoKg8Uzlvyj3byQreVBk=

Now Decryption at Crypto End

```
CryptoJS.AES.decrypt('MURKOx14eSOo2vs8ZQyCpXpsoKg8Uzlvyj3byQreVBk=', CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(HexKeyForJS), {iv: CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(HexInitVectorForJS), padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7}).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
```

Cheers :)

Comment: Underrated answer. Got my example working with this.